# Magento 2 : External link in admin order grid not linking when click

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, knockout

I have an extra column in my **Magento 2 admin order grid**, with a column with external urls. This is working well (I see an overview of al my hyperlinks).

But when I click on a url, I go to the order detail page instead of my external url.
I suppose, this is due the "data-bind" Knockout code.
How can I make working urls? Can I disable the onclick events for a single column?

**(tricks like css z-index:999 are not working...)**

Answer (score 15):

If You are using custom class for rendering column ( for example **`<column name="link" class="My\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Link">`**) which convert your column value to link html along with cells html js ui component (**`<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>`**) you can disable default action which fires on grid row click by adding to your column config item:

**`<item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>`**

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I missed to add `<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue for **UI grid** and resolved it by rewriting component for current cell:

**Vendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/my_grid_listing.xml** file:

```
<column name="link">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Link</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_MyModule/js/grid/cells/link</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="disableAction" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

and disabled function `getFieldHandler()` in:

**Vendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/cells/link.js**

```
define([
        'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column'
    ],
    function (Column) {
        'use strict';

        return Column.extend({
            defaults: {
                bodyTmpl: 'Vendor_MyModule/grid/cells/link',

            },

            getFieldHandler: function (record) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Template:

**Vendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/template/grid/cells/link.html**

```
<a class="action-menu-item"
   text="$col.getLabel($row())"
   attr="href: $col.getLabel($row())"
   target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can create Render File for clickable that URL.

**URL.php** inside Renderer Folder

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Tab\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
class Url extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        $rowId = $row->getId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        return '<a target="_blank" href="'.$baseUrl.'">'.$baseUrl.'</a>';
    }
}
```

And inside your **Grid.php**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('id', [
        'header'    => __('URL'),
        'index'     => 'id',
        'renderer'  => 'Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Url'
    ]);
}
```

Your URL will be clickable and open that URL in new tab. Hope it helps :)